# . . .faulty Caesar cipher java program . . .

Tags: java

This is Caesar cipher program, In this Program Decryption process works completely but encryption process have problem. help me to solve this problem.

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class test1 {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int choice;
        System.out.println("Welcome to Caesar cipher program");
        System.out.println("enter the String");
        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine());
        System.out.println("enter your choice");
        System.out.println("1. Encryption");
        System.out.println("2. Decryption");
        choice = (int) System.in.read();
        switch(choice) {
         case '1':
            System.out.println("encrypting the String . . ." + str);
            for(int j=0; j<str.length(); j++){
                for(int i=0; i<256; i++) {
                    if(str.charAt(j) == (char)i){
                        str.setCharAt(j, (char)(i+3));
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("encrypted String . . ." + str);
         break;
         case '2':
            System.out.println("Decrypting the String . . ." + str);
            for(int j=0; j<str.length(); j++){
                for(int i=0; i<256; i++) {
                    if(str.charAt(j) == (char)i){
                        str.setCharAt(j, (char)(i-3));
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Decrypted String . . ." + str);
         break;
        }
        }
    }
```

this is program print the value from ascii code.

Comment: "Program Decryption process works completely but encryption process have problem" Doesnt help. Whats the problem?

Comment: _encryption process have problem_ is not a helpful problem description. Do you get an error? Please include sample input plus expected and actual output otherwise.

Comment: BTW, your inner for-loop (in both cases) is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `break;` in your inner loop just after `str.setCharAt(j, (char)(i+3))` and `str.setCharAt(j, (char)(i-3))` for both cases. Then it will be fine.

Now if I enter string `aj` then incription will be `dm`.
If I enter `dm` then decription will be `aj`.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problems are your inner loops. What you are doing is basically:

- is this an 'a'? If yes, add 3
- is this a 'b' ? If yes, add 3
- is this a 'c' ? If yes, add 3
- is this a 'd' ? If yes, add 3
  ...

This completely unnecessary. Just take the character, and add 3.

OK, unnecessary does not imply wrong. Where it goes wrong, is that you keep checking after you add 3.

If the character is an 'a', you add 3 and get 'd'. Three iterations later in your loop you discover: this is a 'd', lets add 3. Not you got 'g'. Three iterations later you add 3 to your 'g', and so on.

So, a break statement, as suggested by AJ. would help.

On the other hand: the best solution is to just lose the inner loop:

```
System.out.println("encrypting the String . . ." + str);
for(int j=0; j<str.length(); j++){
   char c = str.charAt(j);
   str.setCharAt(j, (char)(c+3));
}
System.out.println("encrypted String . . ." + str);
```

dto. for the decrypting part